# Mysql and PHP query to get first row in child table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have many tables in a database named india.

Table name : information, it looks like this: (I am showing only 3 columns but it really has many.)

```
primary_key place_name  email
1           Bangalore   abc@xyz.com
2           Mumbai      abc@xyz.com
3           pune        abc@xyz.com
4           chennai     abc@xyz.com
5           delhi       abc@xyz.com
```

Another table data : it looks like this

```
primary_key    value    name
2              85       name1
2              85       name2
4              85       name1
4              85       name2
3              85       name1
3              85       name2
1              85       name1
1              85       name2
1              85       name3
```

So wherever there is a match up in primary key of table data, I want to get information from 1st table

Expected output is like this

```
2     Mumbai    abc@xyz.com    2    85    name1 
2     Mumbai    abc@xyz.com    2    85    name2
....
....
```

and output show be in ascending order that is by using primary key, I really new to web programming please help me how to do this using php, and I want print this on html page in center, kindly do the needful I will accept your answer if its fulfills my need, I am beginner

Comment: In second tbl pk is not unique please mension exact data

Comment: Is the primary_key in the second table is actually a reference of the primary_key in the first???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT t1.primary_key, t1.place_name, t1.email, t2.primary_key, t2.value, t2.name 
FROM table1_name t1 INNER JOIN table2_name t2
ON t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key ORDER BY t1.primary_key";
```

**Display your data from***

```
$queryResult=mysql_query($query);

function mysql_fetch_all($result) {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $return[] = $row;
  }
  return $return;
}

$getResult= mysql_fetch_all($queryResult);
echo $getResult[0]." ".$getResult[1]." ".$getResult[2]." ".$getResult[3]." ".$getResult[4];
```

Comment: Thank you so much answer accepted..what `mysql_fetch_all` does ?

Comment: mysql_fetch_all() function return you an array which contain your desired value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need your help in future also, I am learning php and mysql

Answer (score 1):

It's easy you have to connect them by the query ex:

```
SELECT t1.primary_key, t1.place_name, t1.email, t2.primary_key, t2.value, t2.name 
FROM table1_name t1, table2_name 
WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key;
```

but you need whole fields so you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1_name t1, table2_name 
WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key;
```

Hope that can help you.

Comment: did you see t2.primary_key is not primary key `FYI`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2
where t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key
order by t1.primary key
```